# Issue placing three-divs; third div somehow affects whole page

Tags: css, html

I have three divs in a row which will ultimately contain three, "widgets," (calendar, YouTube playlist, and an audio podcast). When I apply a width of 30% to the first two DIVs everything works, but when I apply any width to the third DIV it causes the whole page to shift left, (absolute position left:0). Also, any padding added to the DIVs contained within .widgets seems to affect the page. Why are these DIVs, the third in particular, causing so much trouble? and how should I go about achieving the design I have on paper, (in the SkyDrive link)?

[JSFiddle for the results...](http://bit.ly/Wpye1k) 
[SkyDrive folder for screenshots and wireframe](http://sdrv.ms/13yCE82)

Comment: In your example, I suppose the very tiny 1/2/3 at the bottom are in the problematic `<div>`s as you have described? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed some of your code according to requirement have look in updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xMNrW/5/).

Updated CSS Code

```
.events {
    background: red;
    float:left;
    width:33%;

}
.youtube {
    background: green;
    float:left;
    width:31%;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;

}
.audio {
    background: white;
    float:left;
        width:33%;
}
```